# Kinetic: turtlesim and teleop_key. Change keyboard key input?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I’m at the beginning with ROS. I installed the Kinetic on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I would like to understand how I can change the keys to control the turtlesim from the teleop_key (for example, instead of the arrows, the keys w, a, s, d). It can be done? Can someone help me?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283937/kinetic:-turtlesim-and-teleop_key.-change-keyboard-key-input?/) by [cholopineco](https://answers.ros.org/users/33913/cholopineco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, all you need is a node publishing a `geometry_msgs/Twist` message on the correct topic (likely `turtle1/cmd_vel`). There are many keyboard-based teleop nodes that could be used instead of the `turtle_teleop_key`.  For example [teleop_twist_keyboard](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard) or [key_teleop](http://wiki.ros.org/key_teleop). Running one of these nodes with the right remapping would allow you to control the turtlesim using whatever the keybindings of that node are. For example after running your `turtlesim_node` you could run

```
rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py cmd_vel:=turtle1/cmd_vel
```

And then you'd be using the keys described on the [teleop_twist_keyboard page](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard#Controls).

If you really want to change the keys used in the `turtle_teleop_key` node from the tutorial, then the only way to do that would be to have a copy of the source code for the turtlesim package in your workspace, edit the source code, and then recompile. The keys used for driving the turtle are [defined here](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/98753d885775a3347ba6d149afae0ac3df7be772/turtlesim/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp#L7-L11), and they are processed in [this case statement](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/98753d885775a3347ba6d149afae0ac3df7be772/turtlesim/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp#L97-L119). If you wanted to use "wsad", you could change the top defines to be:

```
#define KEYCODE_R 0x64
#define KEYCODE_L 0x61
#define KEYCODE_U 0x77
#define KEYCODE_D 0x73
#define KEYCODE_Q 0x71
```

To read more about why, in the original code, the arrow keys are the specific values they are (e.g. Right=0x43), you could read the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432632/1082525
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code
- https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cholopineco](https://answers.ros.org/users/33913/cholopineco/) on 2018-02-28**:
Thanks a lot jarvisschultz!
The source code where should it be put? I thought about modifying the original one, but I could not find it.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-03-01**:
You need to have the whole package's source code in a workspace. Likely the easiest way to do this is to cd into your workspace/src directory and then run `git clone https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials.git` Now you'd have the whole ros_tutorials metapackage in your workspace.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-03-01**:
After editing the code, you would need to re-compile the package with `catkin_make`.

**Comment by [cholopineco](https://answers.ros.org/users/33913/cholopineco/) on 2018-03-02**:
Thanks a lot! I'll try to immediately follow your advice.